# Renomear campo em uma lambda

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda

No SQL eu faço assim:

```
select campo1 as teste from tabela
```

E em uma *lambda*? Como eu faria? Tenho essa lambda com várias tabelas e o campo `ValuePayment` se repete várias vezes.

```
var qry = db.User.Join(db.Solicitation, user => user.UserID, sol => sol.UserID, (user, sol) => new { user, sol })
                    .Join(db.Payments, sol => sol.sol.SolicitationID, py => py.SolicitationID, (sol, py) => new { sol, py })
                    .Join(db.RefundKM, sol => sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID, km => km.SolicitationID, (sol, km) => new { sol, km })
                    .Join(db.Refund, sol => sol.sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID, re => re.SolicitationID, (sol, re) => new { sol, re })
                    .Select(syn => new
                    {
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeID,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeStatus,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeFirstName,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.user.Grade,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.StatusSolicitation,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.DateFinancing,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Manufacturer,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Chassi,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Model,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.ValueProperty,
                        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.ValueGranted,
                        syn.sol.sol.py.PaymentStatus,
                        syn.sol.sol.py.ValuePayment,
                        syn.sol.sol.py.ValueInterest,
                        syn.sol.km.ValuePayment,
                        syn.re.ValuePayment

                    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somente iguale a propriedade com algum nome de sua preferencia, exemplo:

```
empId = syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeID
```

no seu código algo assim:

```
var qry = db.User.Join(db.Solicitation, user => user.UserID, sol => sol.UserID, (user, sol) => new { user, sol })
    .Join(db.Payments, sol => sol.sol.SolicitationID, py => py.SolicitationID, (sol, py) => new { sol, py })
    .Join(db.RefundKM, sol => sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID, km => km.SolicitationID, (sol, km) => new { sol, km })
    .Join(db.Refund, sol => sol.sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID, re => re.SolicitationID, (sol, re) => new { sol, re })
    .Select(syn => new
    {
        syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeID,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeStatus,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeFirstName,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.user.Grade,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.StatusSolicitation,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.DateFinancing,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Manufacturer,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Chassi,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Model,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.ValueProperty,
        syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.ValueGranted,
        syn.sol.sol.py.PaymentStatus,
        p1 = syn.sol.sol.py.ValuePayment,
        syn.sol.sol.py.ValueInterest,
        p2 = syn.sol.km.ValuePayment,
        p3 = syn.re.ValuePayment
    });
```

nesse exemplo como tem 3 iguais eu renomei para `p1`, `p2` e `p3`, mas, o nome pode ser de sua preferencia.

Answer (score 5):

`syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.` certamente é um dos maiores absurdos que eu já vi em código e algo me diz que não deve parar por aí, mas acho que é isto que deseja:

```
var qry = db.User.Join(db.Solicitation, user => user.UserID, sol => sol.UserID, (user, sol) => new { user, sol })
                .Join(db.Payments, sol => sol.sol.SolicitationID, py => py.SolicitationID, (sol, py) => new { sol, py })
                .Join(db.RefundKM, sol => sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID, km => km.SolicitationID, (sol, km) => new { sol, km })
                .Join(db.Refund, sol => sol.sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID, re => re.SolicitationID, (sol, re) => new { sol, re })
                .Select(syn => new {
                    EmployeeID = syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeID,
                    EmployeeStatus = syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeStatus,
                    EmployeeFirstName = syn.sol.sol.sol.user.EmployeeFirstName,
                    Grade = syn.sol.sol.sol.user.Grade,
                    SolicitationID = syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.SolicitationID,
                    StatusSolicitation = syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.StatusSolicitation,
                    DateFinancing = syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.DateFinancing,
                    Manufacturer = syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Manufacturer,
                    Chassi = syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Chassi,
                    Model = syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.Model,
                    ValueProperty = syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.ValueProperty,
                    ValueGranted = syn.sol.sol.sol.sol.ValueGranted,
                    PaymentStatus = syn.sol.sol.py.PaymentStatus,
                    ValuePayment = syn.sol.sol.py.ValuePayment,
                    ValueInterest = syn.sol.sol.py.ValueInterest,
                    ValuePayment = syn.sol.km.ValuePayment,
                    ValuePaymentRe = syn.re.ValuePayment
                });
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/Join.cs).